# How to detect/inspect element in desktop application developed in SWT?

Tags: testing, automation

I am trying to automate desktop application which was developed by Java SWT. I have tried with the tools such as 'UIAVerify', 'Inspect.exe', 'UISpy', but object or elements in that desktop application not able to identify, could any one help on this?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to find it by using xpath to find parent element and then get

C# + Winium sample:

```
var Edit_Fields = app.FindElements(By.XPath("//*[@ControlType = 'ControlType.Edit']"));'
Edit_Fields[0].Clear();
Edit_Fields[0].SendKeys(user_name);
Edit_Fields[1].SendKeys(passord);
```

Comment: Its not Web application, am trying to automate desktop application.. Your answer won't help me

Comment: I'm add sample to my answer